# Ionic 2 : Test with jasmine and karma error 'ng test'

Tags: node.js, angular, testing, ionic2, karma-jasmine

I try to follow this tutorial :

http://lathonez.com/2017/ionic-2-unit-testing/

And when I run "ng test" I have this error :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile>ng test
27 03 2017 11:55:00.556:ERROR [preprocess]: Can not load "angular-cli", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
No provider for "framework:angular-cli"! (Resolving: framework:angular-cli)
Error: No provider for "framework:angular-cli"! (Resolving: framework:angular-cli)
    at error (C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:22:12)
    at Object.get (C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:9:13)
    at Injector.get (C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:54:19)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:143:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Server._start (C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:142:21)
    at Injector.invoke (C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:75:15)
    at Server.start (C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:103:18)
    at Promise (C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\test.js:35:25)
    at Class.run (C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\test.js:15:16)
    at Class.run (C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\test.js:99:25)
    at Class.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:134:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

I don't understand what I have to do. I had run this command at first :

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli @types/jasmine @types/node jasmine-core jasmine-spec-reporter karma karma-chrome-launcher karma-cli karma-jasmine karma-jasmine-html-reporter karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter
```

It work well, and I add all file mentioned in the tutorial ...

In my test.ts file I have an error in my import :

```
import { getTestBed, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
```

I have : Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing', but it exist in my module folder...

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: try `npm run test`

Comment: this command run the "ng test" command. So I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There looks to be three ways of unit testing ionic 2 projects going around at the moment.

1. angular-cli **( deprecated but works fine for me )**
2. @angular/cli **( new shiny but tricky to upgrade too if you have an angular-cli setup already )**
   http://lathonez.com/2017/ionic-2-unit-testing/
3. Using scripts called by "ionic test" **( see ionic blog for details and link to test example )**
   http://blog.ionic.io/basic-unit-testing-in-ionic/

There will soon be another way too

ionic blog: "We’re also working on baking unit testing right into the Ionic CLI (or more accurately, @ionic/app-scripts). Stay tuned for that."

If you can wait a bit I would wait for Ionic CLI version. It's likely to give you the least amount of problems long run, as the ionic team will keep it running will all the new shiny ionic goodness that comes along.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that the `karma.conf.js`
is still pointing at the old `angular-cli`
this has been renamed to `@angular/cli`.

If you change all the `angular-cli` to `@angular/cli` in your `karma.conf.js` file that should point you in the right direction.

The format of the `karma.conf.js` has also changed so it may need to be updated.

For Update docs see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-rc.0-update

Comment: I update my karma.conf.js and I have this new error : "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" when I run ng test ...

Comment: I have reverted to using angular-cli.

Comment: @V.Pivet - I had the same problem, eventually I fixed it by changing the "main" entry in angular-cli.json - Ionic 2 places main.ts in "src/app", while Angular places it in "src".