# ng test fails, Angular6

Tags: angular

I have a project which is upgraded from Angular4 to 6.

Everything is good, but ng test is not working:

```
ERROR [karma-server]: Server start failed on port 9876: Error: No provider for "framework:@angular/cli"! (Resolving: framework:@angular/cli)
```

Please help

**karma.conf.js**

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli' , '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],    
    files: [
      {pattern: './node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css', included: true, watched: true}
    ],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'), reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },

    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    autoWatchBatchDelay: 3000,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: [
          // See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md
          '--headless',
          '--disable-gpu',
          // Without a remote debugging port, Google Chrome exits immediately.
          '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
        ],
      }
    } 
  });
};
```

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043428/ionic-2-test-with-jasmine-and-karma-error-ng-test ?

Comment: What's your karma.conf.js file look like?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43047847/9386929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `@angular-devkit/build-angular` to make your karma works.

First, make sure you have that line in the `karma.conf.js`:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
```

and in your requires: require `('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')`

Then add it in you dev dependecies with that command:

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular --save-dev
```

Comment: I have added my karma.conf. It look ok

Answer (score 1):

The solution in `angular 9`  is delete the file `node_modules` after execute `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from angularV4 to v6 has lot of changes that includes angular-cli change too. It has been  renamed to `@angular/cli`.

make sure all the references to the old `angular-cli` has been renamed to `@angular/cli`.

If you change all the `angular-cli` to `@angular/cli` in your `karma.conf.js` file you should be be good to go.

The format of the `karma.conf.js` has also changed in angular v6 onwards so it may need to be updated.